# How to fill value on daily level into dataframe instead of null

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe which contains columns as shown

```
Unique_id        date                type

1          2018-03-21 12:05:31        a
1          2018-03-21 12:05:32        None
1          2018-03-21 12:05:33        None
1          2018-03-21 12:05:34        None
1          2018-03-21 12:05:35        None
1          2018-03-21 12:05:36        None
1          2018-03-21 12:05:37        None
2          2018-03-21 12:05:31        b
2          2018-03-21 12:05:32        None
2          2018-03-21 12:05:33        None
2          2018-03-21 12:05:34        None
```

Now the type can change after certain days but not in same day. What I am trying to achieve and cannot figure out how to do is take the value which is received once a day and then fill all None received for that day with that value. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Spark Window to solve such a problem. Assuming there's only one row per day where type is not null:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window    

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([ 
    [(1),('2018-03-21 12:25:01'), ('a')],
    [(1),('2018-03-21 12:25:02'), (None)],
    [(1),('2018-03-22 12:25:03'), ('b')],
    [(1),('2018-03-22 12:25:04'), (None)],
    [(2),('2018-03-21 12:25:01'), ('c')],
    [(2),('2018-03-21 12:25:02'), (None)],
    [(2),('2018-03-21 12:25:03'), (None)],
], ['id', 'date', 'type'])

df2 = df.select('*', F.to_date('date', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('date2'))

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('id', 'date2')
typee = F.max('type').over(windowSpec)

df3 = df2.select('id', 'date', typee.alias('type'))
df3.show()
>>>
+---+-------------------+----+
| id|               date|type|
+---+-------------------+----+
|  2|2018-03-21 12:25:01|   c|
|  2|2018-03-21 12:25:02|   c|
|  2|2018-03-21 12:25:03|   c|
|  1|2018-03-22 12:25:03|   b|
|  1|2018-03-22 12:25:04|   b|
|  1|2018-03-21 12:25:01|   a|
|  1|2018-03-21 12:25:02|   a|
+---+-------------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

After Study from this above answer and my own trial and error found a suitable solution through Forward Filling for my problem specifically.